# Which content type should use for all types of files to download file in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have functionality to download file in asp.net. I have bytes, filename and size. I have tried by following way but whenever I open file, it doesn't open correctly. If it's jpg or png file, it doesn't display picture.

Here is my code on button click:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(getStringFromServer());
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Charset = "";
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

I have read somewhere that I need to specify ContentType. But in my case, file can be of any type.

Can anybody please guide me appropriate way?

Comment: Well the fact that you're using `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()` is probably the cause here. Why does your (unconventionally named) `getFileBytes()` method return a string rather than a byte array?

Comment: `Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";` give this a proper `ContentType`, for instance, for `jpg` you had `image/jpg` or such.. also as JonSkeet mentioned, avoid `Encoding.ASCII` if possible just pass it as binary.

Comment: also, what does `getStringFromServer()` actually do..?

Comment: @BagusTesa But I get string as an response from server. I must convert string to bytes as I have tried. Is there any other utilised method to convert string to bytes? please suggest.

Comment: @BagusTesa `getStringFromServer()` get strings from server. I get file content as an string from server.

Comment: wait, how does the `string` looks like..? if it's in [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) you ought to do something...

Comment: @BagusTesa Yes. It can be base64. Should I convert it using Base64?

Comment: yep, just decode the base64, pass the binary, put a proper content type - anyway, i'm a bit hesitant regarding the header part.. so.. keep experimenting, you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem and solve it with very simple way
usually your file name has file type So i use this code:

```
 string fileType = fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        if (FileFetchManager.IMAGE_TYPES.Contains(fileType, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase, true))
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "image/" + FileFetchManager.ConvertFileExtensionToImageFormat(fileType).ToString();
        else
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/" + fileType;
```

this is my FileFetchManager class:

```
  public class FileFetchManager
{
    public const string DEFAULT_FILE_TYPE = "txt";

    public static readonly string[] IMAGE_TYPES = { "bmp", "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "tiff", "tif" };

    public static string GetFileFetchUrl(string TableName, string FieldName, string FileNameFieldName, string PrimaryKeyValue)
    {
        return GetFileFetchUrl(TableName, FieldName, FileNameFieldName, PrimaryKeyValue, null);
    }

    public static string GetFileFetchUrl(string TableName, string FieldName, string FileNameFieldName, string PrimaryKeyValue, int? thumbnailImageSize)
    {
        return QueryStringCoder.CodeUrl("~/UserControl/JcoDataGrid/DBFileFetch.aspx?t=" + TableName + "&f=" + FieldName + "&fnf=" + FileNameFieldName + "&i=" + PrimaryKeyValue + (thumbnailImageSize == null ? "" : "&s=" + thumbnailImageSize));
    }

    public static string GetFileFetchUrl(string fileBytesSessionName, string fileName)
    {
        return GetFileFetchUrl(fileBytesSessionName, fileName, null);
    }

    public static string GetFileFetchUrl(string fileBytesSessionName, string fileName, int? thumbnailImageSize)
    {
        return QueryStringCoder.CodeUrl("~/UserControl/JcoDataGrid/MemoryFileFetch.aspx?sn=" + fileBytesSessionName + "&fn=" + fileName + (thumbnailImageSize == null ? "" : "&s=" + thumbnailImageSize));
    }

    public static string GetFileType(string fileName)
    {
        if (fileName.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
            return DEFAULT_FILE_TYPE;
        return fileName.Substring(fileName.IndexOf(".") + 1);
    }

    public static bool IsImage(string fileName)
    {
        string fileType = fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        bool isImage = FileFetchManager.IMAGE_TYPES.Contains(fileType, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase, true);
        return isImage;
    }

    public static byte[] GetThumbnailImage(string fileName, byte[] imageBytes, int size)
    {
        if (size <= 0)
            throw new Exception("ErrorCode : 1390/10/23-22:04 : " + QueryStringCoder.Code("اندازه درخواستي جهت تامبنيل تصوير(" + size + ") مجاز نمي باشد!"));
        ImageFormat imageType = ConvertFileExtensionToImageFormat(GetFileType(fileName));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
        ms.Position = 0;
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
        int width;
        int height;
        if (img.Height > img.Width)
        {
            height = size.ToInt();
            width = img.Width * size.ToInt() / img.Height;
        }
        else //if (img.height <= img.width)
        {
            width = size.ToInt();
            height = img.Height * size.ToInt() / img.Width;
        }
        if (imageType == ImageFormat.Png || imageType == ImageFormat.Gif)
        {                
            System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort myCallback = new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);
            img = img.GetThumbnailImage(width, height, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero);
            imageType = ImageFormat.Png;
        }
        else
            img = ImageResizer.ConstrainProportions(img, height, Dimensions.Height);
        MemoryStream thumbnailImageStream = new MemoryStream();
        thumbnailImageStream.Position = 0;
        img.Save(thumbnailImageStream, imageType);
        return thumbnailImageStream.ToArray();
    }

    public static bool ThumbnailCallback()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public static ImageFormat ConvertFileExtensionToImageFormat(string fileExtension)
    {
        switch (fileExtension.ToLower())
        {
            case "jpeg":
            case "jpg":
                return ImageFormat.Jpeg;
            case "bitmap":
            case "bmp":
                return ImageFormat.Bmp;
            case "gif":
                return ImageFormat.Gif;
            case "icon":
            case "ico":
                return ImageFormat.Icon;
            case "png":
                return ImageFormat.Png;
            case "tiff":
            case "tif":
                return ImageFormat.Tiff;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            //break;
        }
    }

    public static void SetResposeContentType(string fileName)
    {
        string fileType = fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        if (FileFetchManager.IMAGE_TYPES.Contains(fileType, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase, true))
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "image/" + FileFetchManager.ConvertFileExtensionToImageFormat(fileType).ToString();
        else
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/" + fileType;
    }
}
```

i hope it's useful for you

Comment: playing blind, `getStringFromServer()` only had a `string` to represent the file content, oh well! but it's not a bad idea though, if only op had the filename.

Comment: @BagusTesa yes your rigth but Nanji  said " I have filename and size"

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the content type is to allow the user agent (UA) to determine the type of the downloaded resource. Without a content type, the downloaded content is just naked data which could be anything.

It might be possible in some cases to infer the content type, but that is highly dependent on context. If the content is an image, the UA could infer the image type, if the content is text, it can check for a byte order mark etc. But since the data can be just about anything, it is impossible for the UA to do such an inferrence.

You have specified the content type `application/octet-stream`. That means you are telling the UA that the content is binary data. And that's how the UA is treating it. If you want the data to be recognized as an image, you need to specify the correct content type; `application/octet-stream` will not be enough.

When you store data that can be of any type, it is absolutely necessary for you to store the MIME type with the data. If you read the data from disc, you might be able to inder the content type from the file extension, but your server needs to do that, because the UA can't.